# i want to send parameters to function in an array

Tags: php, arrays, function

i am trying to use this code:

```
$arr = [
  function ($a) {
    return $a + $a;
},
  function ($b) {
    return $b * $b;
},
  function ($c,$cc) {
    return $c % $cc - $c;
},
  function ($d) {
    return $d + 4 / $d;
 }
];
```

how can i pass parameters to this functions?
i have already learned this statment for function with no arguments. for example:
 function () { echo 'somethings'; } that's mean this function in an array don't have incoming arguments.

```
$test = rand (0,1);
echo $myarr[$test]();
```

In addition

can i change (rand) statment with other statment in the above code snippet?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following:

Your array:

```
$arr = [
    function ($a) {
        return $a + $a;
    },
    function ($b) {
        return $b * $b;
    },
    function ($c,$cc) {
        return $c % $cc - $c;
    },
    function ($d) {
        return $d + 4 / $d;
    }
];
```

Your rand

```
$test = rand(0,1);
```

---- note ----

you can change your rand() to any other statement provided that it an existing index of the $arr array. in order to know if $test value is an index which exists in the $arr array, you can do

```
if (isset($arr[$test])) {}
```

---- end note ---

to call the functions

```
$returnedValue = call_user_func($arr[$test], 10);
echo $returnedValue;
```

Comment: can i call above function (in an array) whit other ways or not?( my mean's using $test variable. without using a variable).